# Settings for report directory in robot framework do not prevail in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have a robot framework project with Robocorp and Language Server extensions in Visual Studio Code. My purpose is to get the test results in an automatically created timestamped directory when I use the VSC provided "Run tests" button for running.

Now I use the following command in terminal to get the test results in an automatically created timestamped directory:

```
robot --timestampoutputs -d .\reports\YYYY-mm-dd-HH-MM tests.robot
```

But when I use Run button, all the output files are generated in the workspace folder without timestamp.
I tried to add the above used arguments to the run configuration in launch.json, but it has no effect on the result files. I used the following configuration:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "robotframework-lsp",
            "name": "Robot Framework: Launch .robot file",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "^\"\\${workspaceFolder}\"",
            "target": "^\"\\${file}\"",
            "terminal": "integrated",
            "env": {},
            "args": [
                "--timestampoutputs",
                "-d",
                "^\"\\${workspaceFolder}\\reports\""
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I tried also to add the same arguments in the robot.yaml file, which had neither any effect on the result files. I used the following settings in the robot.yaml file:

```
tasks:
  Run all tasks:
    shell: python -m robot --timestampoutputs -d ./reports/ tasks.robot

condaConfigFile: conda.yaml
artifactsDir: reports
PATH:
  - .
PYTHONPATH:
  - .
ignoreFiles:
  - .gitignore
```

I am not allowed to run bat files according to the company's security policy.
How can I solve that Run button would create report files in the same way as the manual command sent in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add some rows to the run_robot__main__.py file main method:

```
    from datetime import datetime

    datestring = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    robot_args = args[3:]

    # Always add the listener (because even when not debugging we want
    # to be able to provide output messages for logging as well as
    # information to be show in the `Robot Output` View).
    # 
    robot_args = [
        "--listener=robotframework_debug_adapter.listeners.DebugListener",
        "--listener=robotframework_debug_adapter.listeners.DebugListenerV2",
        "--outputdir=C:/Temp/RobotReports/"+datestring,
    ] + robot_args
```

The file run_robot__main__.py can be found under path:
C:\Users[user].vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-x.x.x\src\robotframework_debug_adapter\